# Adding trace logs when post authorization using UseJwtBearerAuthentication

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc, owin

I have a asp.net mvc website with auth configured as below

```
app.UseJwtBearerAuthentication(
new JwtBearerAuthenticationOptions
{
    TokenValidationParameters = new TokenValidationParameters()
    {
        AudienceValidator = ValidateAudience,
        ValidIssuer = GlobalUri,
        SaveSigninToken = true,
        IssuerSigningKeyResolver = await IssuerSigningKeyResolverAsync(),

    }
});
```

My question is I want to add trace logs when a user is authenticated or otherwise.

Unfortunately, I don't see a hook where I can do some post processing after auth in owin pipeline. Or is there an other way ?

Comment: you mention aspnet but aspnet is big, do you use aspnet webforms, MVC or WebApi?

Comment: I use asp.net mvc. I have editing my question to be more clear now. thanks for pointing out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you have to use **filters** in order to log the user activity, you can create a filter this way

```
 public class UserActivityFilter : ActionFilterAttribute, IActionFilter
    {

        void IActionFilter.OnActionExecuting(ActionExecutingContext actionExecutedContext)
        {
            Log(actionExecutedContext);
            base.OnActionExecuting(actionExecutedContext);
        }

        private void Log(ActionExecutingContext filterContext)
        {
            //Your logic log here
        }
    }
```

Then register your filter in App_Start\FilterConfig.cs

```
public class FilterConfig
    {
        public static void RegisterGlobalFilters(GlobalFilterCollection filters)
        {
            filters.Add(new UserActivityFilter());
        }
    }
```